# Efficient way to accumulate in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, accumulate

I would like to calculate an exponential moving average on a Pandas time series.

I have two columns, one called 'value' and one called 'time'. Time is nondecreasing. I can as well reset the index as 'time' and get the value Series.

[ewma](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewma.html) uses only integer "time" values.

Instead of calculating

```
ewma[i+1] = value[i+1] + alpha * ewma[i]
```

like ewma, I would like to do:

```
ewma[i+1] = value[i+1] + exp(alpha * (time[i] - time[i+1]) ) * ewma[i]
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

numpy.accumulate requires numpy.ufunc.

Comment: maybe with Pandas Rolling Apply ? You can specify your function there with lambda https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html

Comment: @KacperWolkowski I think we can forget all the Rolling methods because you can only take a finite number of antecedents into account. If we take it too small, it makes the result false. If it is big, it works only here because the decay is strong. Moreover, it has complexity len(df) * window

Comment: `expanding` rather than `moving`?  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html

Comment: If you want pure python, (IE, no numpy) why is this tagged numpy / pandas?

Comment: @StephenRauch   This was originally tagged w/ pandas & accumulate.  I edited to add python & numpy figuring over-tagging was better than under-tagging here.

Comment: @JohnE, I came here looking for a pandas question, and the OP expressly rejected with python-only, so...

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to restrict the possibilities. I edited the question to remove this sentence. I meant that I don't want to code a numpy ufunc in C/C++.

Comment: Finally, I did the following: 1. compute all the coefficients 2. multiply and use np.cumsum 3. divide to renormalize each term